# Proper best way to only show information/update the main gui

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point, solid-principles

first of all, this may be stupid/dumb question but anyway, this is not a problem, basically im searching for the best proper way to show a result from a class to the main window.
now i will show you what i need, and then how i would solved this with my current knowledge, knowing that its incorrect way,

---

[image]

so on button click i do this:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new Notification().DoNotify(txtMessage.Text);
        }
```

---

the classes definitions are:

```
public class Notification
    {
        private IMessenger _iMessenger;
        public Notification()
        {
            _iMessenger = new Email();
        }
        public void DoNotify(string Message)
        {
            _iMessenger.SendMessage(Message);
        }
    }

interface IMessenger
    {
        void SendMessage(string Message);
    }

public class SMS : IMessenger
    {
        public void SendMessage(string Message)
        {
            // i want code that will print this message variable to the txtSMS textbox.
        }
    }

    public class Email : IMessenger
    {
        public void SendMessage(string Message)
        {
            // i want code that will print this message variable to the txtEmail textbox.
        }
    }
```

now how to update the main window GUI from these classes?,

one solution that i would use is, add new tempclass with the mainwindow object inside, and then access it,

```
public class TempClass
    {
        public static MainWindow Main;
    }
```

in main  window constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TempClass.Main = this;
        }
```

and the sms/email classes:

```
public class Email : IMessenger
    {
        public void SendMessage(string Message)
        {
            TempClass.Main.txtEmail.Text = Message;
        }
    }

    public class SMS : IMessenger
    {
        public void SendMessage(string Message)
        {
            TempClass.Main.txtSMS.Text = Message;
        }
    }
```

now this works, but there just has to be a better way... what do you think and sorry for long post... ://
**is there any principle or design pattern about this ?**

Comment: [Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: i agree, i actually used events for this kind, but i forgot to mention, ok is there a better way then events?

Comment: You want to update your Gui *when something happens* - That *is* an event. How would you come closer to model that? Just give Email and SMS an event and have the Main register to it - done.

Comment: No need for events and the resulting strong binding - both Windows Forms and WPF offer data binding. By implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface you do inform the subscriber (UI) that there was a change, but you don't need to use a separate event for each kind of data. The data binding mechanism will take care of refreshing the UI

Comment: @ShadyOverflow WPF or Winforms? WPF has multiple MVVM frameworks that already implement what you need. Some, like Caliburn.Micro even use conventions to automagically bind eg the `Messages` listbox to the `Messages` list property on the ViewModel

Comment: Panagiotis is right: For your requirement DataBinding is even more suitable than events.

Comment: Yesterday I answered how to use events for similar scenario.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066836/how-can-i-add-to-a-listbox-from-another-class/43068140#43068140.

Answer (score 0):

A static property is not recommended when you might have two or more instances of your application. You can define a method in MainWindow:

```
internal void SetMessage(string Message)
{
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {txtSMS.Text = Message;}));
}
```

and send the instance of your MainWindow to other classes, whether by a specific constructor

```
MainWindow parentWindow;
void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      if (parentWindow != null)
          _parentWindow.SetMessage(txtMessage.Text);
}
```

or by defining a DependencyProperty and use Binding.

You can also use *Events*, however, I prefer the preceding.